# crontab not executing a python script

Tags: python, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have a python script called `backupapp.py`

```
import subprocess, time
from datetime import date

app_name = 'xxxxx'

capture_backup = subprocess.check_output(['heroku','pg:backups:capture','--app',app_name]) # Make a new backup 

time.sleep(5)

info_backup = subprocess.check_output(['heroku','pg:backups:info','--app',app_name])

name_backup = info_backup[11:15] # Extract the name of the backup database

today = date.today().strftime("%m_%d_%Y")
filename = name_backup + '_' + today + '.dump'

url = subprocess.check_output(['heroku','pg:backups:url', name_backup,'--app',app_name])

url = url[:-1] # Remove \n from the string

print "Beginning Download....."

download_backup = subprocess.check_output(['curl', '-o', filename, url])
```

This script works when I run it in the terminal `python backupapp.py`

However, I want to run this everyday at noon.

So I used `crontab -e` and added this:

```
0 12 * * * cd /Users/myuser/Desktop/Work/appbackup && python backupapp.py
```

But this isn't running. I checked for some answers online to see the logs, but the logs do not exist.

Comment: Did you try with absolute path to python?

Comment: You mean instead of using `cd`, just directly `python /Users/myuser/Desktop/Work/appbackup/backupapp.py`?

Comment: No, I mean `/path/to/python /Users/myuser/Desktop/Work/appbackup/backupapp.py` or `cd /Users/myuser/Desktop/Work/appbackup && /path/to/python backupapp.py`

Comment: If I may make a suggestion (I'm assuming linux) I've pretty much entirely switched from cron to systemd timer files. Slightly more work to set up, *much* easier to manage and troubleshoot. YMMV.

Comment: @JaredSmith, based on the path IMO this is MacOS

Comment: @RomeoNinov yeah, looks like you're correct. But then, IIRC MacOS has it's own task scheduling facilities that are probably going to be easier than cron?

Comment: Do you mean the automator in MacOS?

Answer (score 1):

```
0 12 * * * root cd /Users/myuser/Desktop/Work/appbackup && ./backupapp.py
```

Make sure your python file has a valid shebang at the top with the appropriate path to your python binary like

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Comment: This will work only on specific case! And why do you `root`, in path you will see the username.

Comment: The username in the path is just that, the path to the script that is attempting to be run. `root` here is instructing crontab what user will execute the script. I added root here, but it could be something else I suppose.  Critically important, however, will be that the OP has their shebang in order.

Comment: This (again) will work in specific case. And may not work in MacOS. And in MacOS this is the username (myuser in this case)

Comment: I see what you're saying.  That's correct, the /Users/... does look more like MacOS than other OS's...excellent catch!

Comment: Thanks! Should I change `root` to `myuser` in this case? I am assuming that I also have to make the `.py` file executable with `chmod +x`? A heads up, if I run this in the terminal -- `cd /Users/myuser/Desktop/Work/appbackup && ./backupapp.py`, it works.

Comment: As Romeo Ninov stated, since it looks like you're on MacOS, you shouldn't need to do so, just make sure that you're either using the absolute path to the python binary you want to use to run the script or you have a valid shebang line in the python script itself as the top line.

Comment: I have already tried that with the shebang line, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Then I would simply add the full path to the python binary into your crontab line if you're still having issues.